# Hi , i have written a code to create CloudFormation template using troposphere Getting Syntax error while running the code

Tags: python-3.x, aws-cloudformation, troposphere

i have written a code to create CloudFormation template using troposphere where i am creating EC2 instance and assiging SG and EIP but getting error while running python code. Code is below:

````
from troposphere import Ref, Template, join, GetAtt, Parameter
import troposphere.ec2 as ec2

template = Template()

#Creating Security Group

SSHSecurityGroup = ec2.SecurityGroup('SSHSecurityGroup')
SSHSecurityGroup.GroupDescription = "Enable SSH access bia port 22"
SSHSecurityGroup.SecurityGroupIngress = [
    ec2.SecurityGroupRule(
        CidrIP="0.0.0.0/0",
        FromPort="22",
        IpProtocol="tcp",
        ToPort="22",
        )]

ServerSecurityGroup = ec2.SecurityGroup('ServerSecurityGroup')
ServerSecurityGroup.GroupDescription("Allow access from specified CIDR range")
ServerSecurityGroup.SecurityGroupIngress = [
    ec2.SecurityGroupRule(
        IpProtocol="tcp",
        FromPort="80",
        ToPort="80",
        CidrIp="0.0.0.0/0",
        IpProtocol="tcp",
        FromPort="22",
        ToPort="22",
        CidrIP="192.168.1.1/32",
    )]
template.add_resource(SSHSecurityGroup)
template.add_resource(ServerSecurityGroup)
#Creating EC2 Instance
ec2_instance = template.add_resource(ec2.Instance("MyEC2Intsance",
    ImageId="ami-i23df45832",
    AvailabilityZone="us-east-2",
    InstanceType="t2.micro",
    EIP=Ref(MyEIP),
    SecurityGroups=[Ref(SSHSecurityGroup),Ref(ServerSecurityGroup)],
    ))

#Creating EIP
MyEIP = ec2.EIP("MyEIP", InstanceId=Ref(MyEC2Intsance)
#template.add_resource(MyEIP)
print(template.to_yaml())```
````

Comment: It would be helpful to know what error you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line needs a trailing (closing) paren:
Change this:

MyEIP = ec2.EIP("MyEIP", InstanceId=Ref(MyEC2Intsance)

to this:

MyEIP = ec2.EIP("MyEIP", InstanceId=Ref(MyEC2Intsance))

And there are other issues with the SecurityGroupIngress/SecurityGroupRules but don't know how to guide since not sure what you're attempting.